# About microsoft graph query for last photos

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to retrieve a last photos in my OneDrive images directory and order it for 'takenDateTime' attribute in 'photo'.

I tried with this with this query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/myimages/test:/search(q='.jpg')?select=name,id,webUrl,eTag,createdDateTime,lastModifiedDateTime/orderby=takenDateTime/photo%20desc`

but the `orderby` seems not to work.

I have tried with 'lastModifiedDateTime' too but the list isn't sorted

How I can retrieve a list and order for more recent photo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The search request doesn't support orderby or filter.

Bye.

A $search request returns up to 250 results. You cannot use $filter or $orderby in a search request.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search